# Want a free video joiner for Windows

Tags: windows, video-editing

I am looking for a free video joiner for Windows XP and beyond, 
I have done a Google search for one, but the software only works with Vista.
Here is the one I am referring to, 
http://www.freevideojoiner.com/

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest taking a look at [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/):

- Free, Open Source
- Cross Platform - *but you will need to find an older build to run on XP, recent builds should be fine on Win7 and later*.
- Supports just about every video format as input and most as output
- Command Line interface
- Lots of options for splitting, joining, converting videos

*If you cannot find one that can run on XP and your hardware will not support later editions I would suggest considering moving over to Linux.*

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP and Windows 7 (at least), you could use Windows Movie Maker, included free with windows, and being able to do video joining, plus other things as well.

Regarding its availability on Windows XP: [from a Microsoft forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/moviemaker-av/i-want-movie-maker-on-windows-xp-3/53a4aa6a-55d0-4f96-99d3-8411b2f3d6a9)